# How to search for findElementBy.id in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm starting with selenium webdriver.
I am trying to make a simple example and look for the button next on the web:
www.lot.com/pl/en.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String web = "https://www.lot.com/pl/en/";
driver.get(web);

try{
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit-booker") );
    System.out.println("FOUND");
}catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I'm not able to get it to work fine
And gives me the following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #submit-booker

What am I doing wrong?
How can i fix it?

Comment: put some wait before finding element.

Comment: I have added  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); before the try, but it doen´t work

Comment: Set implicit wait `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` before `driver.findElement(By.id("submit-booker") );`

Comment: @a_a Thnaks a lot. Perfect

Comment: please mark my answer below as accepted if it worked. @mvillegas

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to `click()` on the `Next` button which have a `span` tag you can consider to construct an unique `xpath` as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='submit-booker']/span") );
```

Comment: I put your code but the same error: Unable to locate element: //button[@id='submit-booker']/span

Comment: If `id` attribute is there, why you use, `xpath` locator

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Webdriver fails to identify the elements with direct identification strategies. you need to write some xpath to identify the elements with the help of driver.findElement(By.xpath("......")) method.
 you can find more about writing xPaths at this link.

```
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/choosing-effective-xpath/
```

if you share the exact html code of the page, someone can help you finding that element.

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced similar issues in the past where Selenium did not detect elements and mentioned as not displayed. If you are trying to click the button you can use javascript.

```
driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('submit-booker').click()")
```

Well it appears that you are trying to fill up the form and move to the search result page to get the prices. If this is the case, you can simplify this task by building the url and opening this directly.

```
 https://bookerproxy.lot.com/service.php?COUNTRY_CODE=PL&LANGUAGE_CODE=en&ORIGIN=WAW&DESTINATION=VIE&DEPARTURE_DATE=07092017&ARRIVAL_DATE=11092017&ADULT_COUNT=1&SENIOR_COUNT=0&CHILD_COUNT=0&INFANT_COUNT=0&PARTNER=L76OK50SI42D&CLASS=E
```

If you look at the URL, it would give you the fields required to fill up just after the "&"

Comment: Just noticed "submit-booker" will expand the form, you need to submit after filling up. The code for that would be
driver.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('booker-column-3')[1].children[0].click()")

Answer (score 0):

Set implicit wait like this-

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

before

```
driver.findElement(By.id("submit-booker") );
```

Comment: Can you explain your code, why you put this code `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: @JainishKapadia Immediately after opening the page he was looking for an element. This implicit wait will allow him to wait for the time till the page loaded completely. This wait will be available till the lifecycle of the driver.

Comment: But instead of providing `implicit wait` here, you should go with `explicit wait`.

Comment: @JainishKapadia yes we can, but this implicit wait is one-time activity and once define it will be valid all over the pages. We can use explicit wait with condition if particular element taking more time.

Comment: Yes, I know that but rather than wait for all element, We should wait for only located one elements, that's why i am telling you to use for `explicit wait`. And it make sense to use `explicit wait`here, instead of `implicit wait`

Comment: @JainishKapadia yes that's true. The localized wait is always better.